# autorefreshing an image in HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a webpage and looking to autorefresh an image in my directory every second. I have code written but I'm not sure why its not working.

```
<html>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
var t = 1 // Interval in Seconds
images = new Array('foo.png'); //URLs of the Images 

function Start() { 
tmp = new Date(); 
tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime();
for (i=1;i<image.length;i++){
document.getElementById("img"+i).src = images[i]+tmp; 
}
setTimeout("Start()", t*1000) 
} 
Start(); 
</SCRIPT>

<body>
 <IMG src="foo.png" border="1" name="refresh" id="img1"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, array index starts from 0 not from 1, your looping variable start with 1, but the array has only 1 item at index 0, so `images[1]` will return undefined.

```
var t = 1 // Interval in Seconds
images = new Array('foo.png'); //URLs of the Images 

function Start() {
  var tmp = "?" + new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("img" + (i + 1)).src = images[i] + tmp;
  }
  setTimeout("Start()", t * 1000)
}
Start();
```

Comment: I understood that mistake but the code still doesn't seem to be working..The test case I'm trying: 
Create an index.html file and saving the contents in the question, opening index.html in chrome, then going into that directory and deleting foo.png. But foo.png still shows in my chrome

Comment: Hi @user3121369, i think the issue is due to browser cache. You can force it not to do, by adding meta tags (e.g. <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">). Check in forum here https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-force-the-users-browser-to-clear-its-cache/18631

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `@Arun P Johny`, array index starts with zero.

You used `i<image.length` in for loop, but your var name is `images`, Note that extra `s`.

Since the value of `i` starts from `0`, set `id` of `<img>` to `img0`

```
<html>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
var t = 1 // Interval in Seconds
images = new Array('foo.png'); //URLs of the Images 

function Start() {
tmp = new Date(); 
tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime();
for (i=0;i<images.length;i++){
document.getElementById("img"+i).src = images[i]+tmp; 
}
setTimeout(Start, t*1000) 
} 
Start();
</SCRIPT>

<body>
 <IMG src="foo.png" border="1" name="refresh" id="img0"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will refresh real-time any image when an image change has been made.

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    $("#logo").each(function(){
       var timeStamp = (new Date()).getTime();
       $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src") + timeStamp );
    });
}, 1000);
</script>
```

This will refresh the div to prevent a long URL from being generated by `?_=' +Math.random()+'`.

```
 <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
          $("#myDIV").load(window.location.href + " #myDIV" );
    }, 80000);
    });
    </script>
```

The image.

```
<div id="myDIV">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png?_=' +Math.random()+'"  width="100%" height="auto" alt="onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src="error.png";"/> 

</div>
```